# get rid of warning when installing registry file

Tags: windows-registry

I use windows vista but this question is for other windows versions as well.

When I double click to install a reg file I get this warning:

> Adding information can unintentionally
>   change or delete values and cause
>   components to stop working correctly.
>   If you do not trust the source of this
>   information in myFile.reg, do not add
>   it to the registry.

Is there any way to get rid of it and from the approval message after?

Comment: Why would you want this, if not for malicious purposes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Regedit.exe supports a /s command-line
>   switch to not display these messages.
>   For example, to silently run the .reg
>   file (with the /s  switch) from a
>   login script batch file, use the
>   following syntax: regedit.exe /s path
>   of .reg file

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516/

That might help you

Answer (score 4):

Change the value of the key:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\regfile\shell\open\command
```

to:

```
regedit.exe /s "%1"
```

Be *VERY* careful after doing so - that warning is there for good reason.